# Messagebox.show is empty on a RestRequest.Content

Tags: c#, messagebox

The following code results in response.Content being the json data(I have confirmed via debugging) from https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2 but the MessageBox that pops up is empty

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2");
        var request = new RestRequest();
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
```

Comment: Are you sure? Unless there's something you're not showing us then there's no reason for the MessageBox to be empty if `response.Content` is populated. If you put `MessageBox.Show("Success!");` or similar I assume the value shows?

Comment: Is the JsonData a string or a streamContent? Maybe it has to be decoded first!?

Comment: You are not sending anything in RestRequest

Answer (score 2):

It looks like its a limitation in string length of the message.show function. Its not supposed to be used with such a large string.

I did the following just to check and it did work.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2");
            var request = new RestRequest();
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            string mystring = response.Content;


            MessageBox.Show(mystring.Substring(0, 1000));
```

This was just to test the theory and it did display the first 1000 characters of the string.

Not sure why you wanted to display the whole string, rather get the correct field value in the json and display it. You know its working because you can debug it and you can see the whole string there.

A post I found : https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/maximum-string-length-for-messagebox-show.3800531/

Anyway I hope this helps you.